# Rspec: doing something before calling some method in class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have a class for example:

```
class BackgroundJob
  def run
    pre_processing
    processing
  end

  def preprocessing
  end

  def processing
  end
end
```

So my code will run is: `BackgroundJob.new.run`. In my rspec, I want to do "something" before calling `processing` method. How can I do this in rspec.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In RSpec, as anywhere else, this can be done by using [`Module#prepend`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#method-i-prepend):

```
BackgroundJob.prepend(Module.new do
  def processing
    puts "do stuff"
    super
  end
end)
```

This approach has a drawback: the modified class will stay with the module prepended, there is no way to “unprepend” already prepended module.

---

The other approach would be to use [Flexmock’s `pass_thru`](https://github.com/jimweirich/flexmock). AFAIK, `pass_thru` might only *append* the additional code to the method, hence one should `flexmock` `preprocessing` method:

```
BackgroundJob.should_receive(:preprocessing).pass_thru do |job|
  job.tap do |job|
    puts "do_stuff"
  end
end
```